# TeXcount cannot fine \input files with a command in the path?

Tags: texcount

UPDATE: The problem I am having is due to having Python code inside a PythonTeX `pycode` environment.  Seems this causes a parsing error with the TeXcount Perl script.

---

I want to use TeXcount to count the words in my thesis.  However, I have either run into a limitation of TeXcount or it's difficult to find an explanation (via documentation, here, forums, etc.) detailing how to alleviate my issue.

I have all the chapters in my thesis in a subfolder from the main .tex document.  I call these via the following line (or similar, depending on the chapter name, obviously):

```
\include{\chaptersPath/background_information}
```

Within many of those chapter files, I have additional files stored a directory deeper for major topics/themes of that chapter, such as:

```
\input{\chaptersPath/background_information/literature}
```

The document compiles fine.  And honestly, I'm not here currently to debate whether my file and directory structure is proper, the most efficient, etc.

I have tried defining `\chaptersPath` variously as:

```
\newcommand{\buildFilesPath}{_build_files}%
```

or

```
\edef\buildFilesPath{./_build_files}%
```

Same behavior for both - The problem I have is that having this command or definition in the `\input` doesn't seem to expand for texcount.  TeXcount complains that the file is not found:

```
[1;31m!!! File not found or not readable: \chaptersPath/background_information !!![0m
```

I tried using `-auxdir` and `-dir`, but these seem to not make TeXcount happy because those commands are still in the `\input` calls.

I also tried including `\immediate\write18{texcount \jobname.tex -inc -out=\buildFilesPath/\jobname.sum}` in the preamble thinking perhaps it would recognize those commands (replaced with plain text path details).  I was wrong; it doesn't.  Funny thing here is that `\buildFilesPath` and `\jobname` *do* get recognized.

Lastly, I've tried playing around with including `\expandafter` and this is totally not useful as well.  It seems the `texcount.exe` (even within the `\immediate\write18` method simply cannot expand those file path definitions).

**Question:**  Is it possible to resolve this problem somehow, while maintaining those commands defining the file/chapter paths?

I realize I can just go through and hardcode all the paths manually.  But this is rather crappy for flexibility, if I want to create a new document using much of the same (La)TeX preamble and base .tex document but with a different file/folder structure.  The current way requires just one change rather than finding and replacing a bunch of stuff every time.

Comment: texcount is a perl script, so you should probably not expect it to be able to expand LaTeX commands.

Comment: Fair enough.  I probably didn't word it as well as I could.  First, I was wondering if there was a way around the lack of expansion.  Second, I thought that by using it via `\immediate\write18`, perhaps it had access to the expansions while LaTeX was in the process of compiling (perhaps putting it in a `shipout` or somewhere similar).  Honestly, I wasn't sure and was hoping for insight from learned people such as yourself!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As daleif has pointed out in a comment, TeXcount does not actually expand LaTeX commands, and so it does not expand the path in `\chaptersPath` when trying to locate the included files.

There is a trick that might work. TeXcount can take instructions embedded in the LaTeX document as comments on the form `%TC:...`. One such instruction is `%TC:subst` which does a simple substitution of a macro with an arbitrary text string. Eg, you could try including somewhere at the top of the document (eg right after the definition of `\chaptersPath`) the command

`%TC:subst \chaptersPath /my/chapters/path`

and see if that does the job. This basically does a simple search and replace. You may have to fiddle around a bit to get the path right (absolute path or relative path?). I'm not entirely sure how it will handle tex files included inside included tex files, but I guess you'll find out if that works out.

---

**Update on bug in TeXcount that causes problems**

The TeXcount solution, as well as other uses file inclusion using `\include`, may fail due to a bug in TeXcount.

When using `\include` to include a TeX file, the `.tex` file type is not required. TeXcount was supposed to add `.tex` to the file name if not already there, but this seems to have failed and was the root cause of the difficulty of getting the solution to work.

This bug can be bypassed by ensuring all file inclusion using `\include` contain the `.tex` file type.

An alternative is to fix the code of TeXcount which is quite simple. Just find the function definition `sub _parse_include_file` and change the line

        `if (!$file=~/\.tex$/i) {$file.='.tex';}`

to

        `if ($file!~/\.tex$/i) {$file.='.tex';}`

and TeXcount should append `.tex` to the file name when required.

Comment: I like that better than my approach -- if it works of course.

Comment: Where is `%TC: subst` documented? I wanted to try the suggestion, but it does not seem to work

Comment: First, thanks for bringing this up.  I didn't notice these options because I was just focused on the command line options.  Without a huge amount  of playing around, I found a couple things.  First, it *only* works one level deep (i.e. it can find files in \chaptersPath but if that file in turn calls one or more `\input`s at a deeper folder, then a `File not found or not readable` message pops up again).  It does seem to be a relative path to the folder where `texcount` is run from (i.e. NOT the .tex folder...unless that happens to be where you run `texcount` from)

Comment: @daleif after seeing this, I realized it's near the bottom of [http://app.uio.no/ifi/texcount/documentation.html](http://app.uio.no/ifi/texcount/documentation.html) in the "TeXcount instructions" section

Comment: @whatisit ahh, details was not listed in the `-help` page for it.

Comment: @daleif The script itself primarily gives help on the command line options. Guess refering to the online or accompanying documentation would by default might be an idea.

Comment: @whatisit It is possible to modify how TeXcount processes paths through the -dir and -dir= options. Default is -dir=. which makes paths relative to the working directory. Not sure if there is any combination that would work without problems: would need to check a bit deeper for that. As I recall, -dir=[path] indicates that included file path will be relative to [path], while -dir without arguments makes them relative to the main file.

Comment: @einar-rødland I was playing around with different things but no luck still.  Relative and absolute paths for  -dir work, but only first first-level `\input`.  The next deeper level `\input`s just seem to break it.  I tried `%TC:subst \chaptersPath E:/PATH/TO/TEX/chapters` in the .tex files inside /chapters and it still breaks.  Message is: `[1;31m!!! File not found or not readable: E:/PATH/TO/TEX/chapters/background_information !!![0m`.  I tried -v4 for more detailed message about why it can't read those deeper `\input`s...but no additional detail is there.

Comment: In the main .tex, including `%TC:subst \chaptersPath chapters` works properly, but `%TC:subst \chaptersPath E:/PATH/TO/TEX/chapters` breaks for some reason.  The -dir option (relative or absolute) seems to make no change.  The -auxdir option works relatively, but absolute path seems to break all the `\input`s (even ones the working with relative path).  I tried replacing the initial `\include` with `\input`, but no change.  Also tried replacing everything with `\import` or just one level (initial or deeper), but no change.  Seems second-level file inputs aren't possible.

Comment: Sorry for all the messages!  I just created a much smaller MWE to test this and the `\input`/`\include` works for multiple levels when the paths are hardcoded.  So, at least that answers one question.  When path command is used in conjunction with `%TC:substr` in the main .tex file and the second level .tex file `\input` is hardcoded - this also works.  In fact, the second level using the path commands is also working in the MWE.  I think my original problem is caused because I am using the `-aux-directory` option when compiling.  I'll play around a bit more and follow up.

Comment: @einar-rødland I figured out my problem.  The problem I am having is due to having Python code inside a PythonTeX `pycode` environment.  Seems this causes a parsing error with the TeXcount Perl script. (I have some print statements inside the Python code which output LaTeX commands to load images).  Removing all the Python stuff suddenly makes everything work as many levels deep as my files go.  Perhaps we could discuss off-list if there is a way to update TeXcount to work around this?

Comment: @whatisit In order to ignore the `pycode` environment, you can either set a rule like `%TC:envir pycode [] xx` (may have to be tweeked) or surround it by lines `%TC:ignore`...`%TC:endignore`. The TeXcount Documentation document explains the details of these commands. Can take this in chat if we find a time we're both online.

Answer (score 4):

As @daleif said in the comments, TeXcount can't parse TeX, being a Perl script.

I don't do Perl so faced with a similar issue I wrote somethign in Python to pre-process the master tex file.

Here's the python script adapted for a minmal version of your case. I call it `tc-paths.py`:

```py
import fileinput # see https://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html
import os
chaptersPath=None
chaptersPathMacro=r'\chaptersPath'
chaptersPathDef=r'\def'+chaptersPathMacro
outfilename=None

for line in fileinput.input():
    if outfilename==None:
        outfilename=os.path.splitext(fileinput.filename())[0]+'-temp'+os.path.splitext(fileinput.filename())[1]
        print ('Writing to: '+outfilename)
        outfile=open(outfilename,'w')
    if chaptersPathDef in line:
        startpos=line.find('{',line.find(chaptersPathDef)+len(chaptersPathDef))+1
        endpos=line.find('}',startpos)
        chaptersPath=line[startpos:endpos]
        print (r'\chaptersPath='+chaptersPath)
        outline=line
    elif r'\input{'+chaptersPathMacro in line:
        print ('Found '+chaptersPathMacro+' in line %d'%fileinput.lineno())  
        outline=line.replace(chaptersPathMacro,chaptersPath)
    else:
        outline=line
    outfile.write(outline)
```

run it with `python tc-paths.py my-master-file.tex`, and it will output to `my-master-file-temp.tex`

A sample input tex file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\chaptersPath{../Chris}
\begin{document}
\input{\chaptersPath/chap1.tex}
\end{document}
```

And the output:

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\chaptersPath{../Chris}
\begin{document}
\input{../Chris/chap1.tex}
\end{document}
```

Then you run texcount on the `-temp.tex` file.

Comment: This script was tested using python 2.7 on windows (hence the lack of `#!/usr/bin/python`).  I think it should work on python 3 as well.  My use of TeXcount with following `\input`/`\include` was all on Linux, so if I've forgotten something in the gap, please let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the help on this!  Let me look more into @einar-rødland's answer and I'll come back to this if necessary.

Comment: As I've been playing around with @einar-rødland's suggestion, I realized I should check with you also about this.  If you use this script, does TeXcount then work for two level deep `\input` / `\include`?  Or have you not tried?

Comment: See the update I included at the top of my original question.  It turns out that TeXcount seems to work fine, as long as I use the `%TC:substr` command in my main .tex file.  I would recommend this for you.  The problem turned out to be caused by using the PythonTeX package and then having Python code inside the preamble (which happens to print out various commands which load images).  It seems this can break TeXcount's parsing ability in a document.

Comment: @whatisit my second level inputs were just tikz figures and tables so I didn't care whether texcount found them or not. Since my thesis I haven't had to worry about texcount.

Comment: It wouldn't work as written for (most) second level inputs as it only opens one file (the master file).